# Why is this question closed and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I'm talking about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14121900/1087848.

It is a kind of obvious solution, but it is a practical and answerable question, it was most probably even a problem that the OP faced. Literally from the FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face.

To me it seems that it is, actually, a good question answering al SO's FAQ's demands.
Then it got a score of -6 (actually -7. but I upvoted)...

*And* it got closed as *not a real question*!
Literally from the grey block saying the question is closed:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form.

- It's absolutely clear what was being asked there, so it is not vague
- All relevant information was present (well, maybe you could argue the OP did not include the error message, but that was not necessary for solving the problem. Anyway, many question on SO don't come with the exception and errors etc. at first. No reason to close).
- It isn't broad, the answer was to change one character, and you could explain why in one sentence.
- It is reasonably answered, so that is possible (or one should assume all people on SO are supernatural, whatever is more likely).
- I wouldn't call it rhetorical.

It couldn't even have been closed as `too localized` because it is a common problem. The only thing I could think of is a duplicate, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Possibly because the OP made no effort to figure out the issue. One run through a debugger would have shown the OP what the issue is, as would a bit of thinking about the loop.

Comment: "why it is not working?" is a terrible problem description. Just because you can guess at what might not be working, the lack of an actual error description makes this a NARQ closing target.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It was one line of code, so I wouldn't say it is diffficult to tell what was not working.

Comment: Sure, but when asking a question, one should be describing what they find is wrong. Leaving it to others to figure out means some will get it wrong.

Comment: @Oded I never do that (I wouldn't even know how), my problem-solving technique with this kind of problems is to look at it until I see the problem. Sometimes I just don't see it and I go to SO (okay, even I would spot this bug, but I hope you got my point).

Comment: It is _answerable_, and it's also _extremely_ localized. I agree with the closure, just not the reason chosen.

Comment: @Oded The code inside the for loop is not being executed, that is almost the same as 'it doesn't work'. There is no error message, just a bit of code is skipped. Someone starting with Java wouldn't know anything better than 'it doesn't work'.

Comment: @TimPost I disagree with that it's extremely localized. It is a common problem, I encounter it often enough (mostly a typo, and I can solve that without SO, but some not).

Comment: Surely the first thing you should do when something doesn't work is to try find out _why_ @11684. The OP hasn't made even a cursory effort to do so... and is instead complaining that it "doesn't work".

Comment: Unfortunately the close reason options given adopt a broader criteria by the community than dictated by the system, often seeing "not a real question" synonymous with "can't believe someone would ask this", for instance.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Thanks, is there a metaquestion that lists these synonyms?

Comment: @11684 The probability of someone having that issue, not noticing the obvious cause, searching for it and then finding _that_ question has got to be negligible. If the question were more along the lines of why Java doesn't warn you about code that will never be executed like that, it would be a much better fit, but still unlikely to help someone frantically searching after mixing `>` with `<`. I'm a little annoyed with the response the OP received in some comments (which I cleaned up), but I strongly agree with the closing.

Comment: @11684: Once you figured out the answer to the question it is of course obvious what is meant by "not working". But if you don't know the answer yet and are trying to solve the problem it would surely make it simpler to know *what* goes wrong. Otherwise you ask yourself all those unnecessary questions, like "Are there any syntax errors?", "Does he access the array out of bounds?", "Is `stringList` even an array? What kind of object is it? Does it have a `get()` that expects an int parameter?". Error search would be much more straight forward with a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: Oh, come on, @sth, not here. It's one short line of code, the typo jumps out. Yes, not a good question at all, but real enough. Too localized. (Although common enough, that sort of typo isn't searchable for the pertinent audience.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He didn't mention what happens when it's "not working". Compiler error? Runtime error? Or did he expect to see something and is he seeing something else? If so, what did he expect to see? The question is too **vague**, thus it was closed as NARQ.

Secondly, he hasn't shown any effort on his own part to grok the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask